# How can I avoid overriding a pure virtual function in a derived class without making it abstract?

Tags: c++, function, object, oop, virtual

Base Class `B` is an abstract class. Classes `M`, and `N` are derived from it (both non-abstract).

Class `B` has a pure virtual function. With current knowledge I know how to override it in `M`, but not in `N`. I cannot leave it pure virtual in `N` given that it is used to instantiate objects, `N` cannot be abstract. How should I do it (by creating an empty do nothing function in N? elegant way to do it?)

The reason I am asking this: let's say, this new function is only supposed to be added for `M` (as I am not aware how to implement it for `N`). Then is there any other way `B` can call this function (originally defined for its child)?

Comment: Instead of describing code, please *show* it. Please [edit] your question to include a [mre], copy-pasted as text. Also please take some time to read [the help pages](http://stackoverflow.com/help), take the SO [tour], read [ask], as well as [how to write the "perfect" question](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/), especially its [checklist](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2012/11/24/stack-overflow-question-checklist/).

Comment: Does a virtual fn that is defined but does nothing in B work ? You override it M only. If you call it on B or N it does nothing. If you call it on M it does something. The whole question suggests your class breakdown isn't quite right...

Comment: "A non-virtual function is defined in B, which should make a call to a function (say func X) supposed to defined only for M.": Are there _two_ functions here or just one? The language indicates _two_. What does the unnamed function have to do with X?

Comment: If it is supposed to be possible to call X through a B pointer/glvalue, then no matter to which kind of object derived from B the pointer/glvalue refers, the call should be possible and call some implementation of X. Otherwise, why should it be allowed to call X through B at all, given that you can't or shouldn't need to know what derived object the pointer/glvalue refers to?

Comment: It all depends on what these classes actually are and what these functions do. Anything from "the callee function should be defined in N and do nothing" to "N should not inherit from B" to "the caller function should not be in B" could potentially be right.

Comment: You might want your function `X` to look similar to `dynamic_cast<M*>(this)->function_in_M();`. But please include what you tried to do as code in your post.

Comment: Sounds like M **is-a** B, but N **is-not-a** B.  Inheritance is probably not the right solution.

Comment: If you give the parent class that method, you are saying that this method can be called on every instance that belongs to that class. Why is it a method for B if it shouldn't be a method for N? Makes no sense. Why not simply remove it from B and only put it in M? The thing you write about the non-virtual function in B sounds like it *should* be different for the child classes, so why not override that one instead?

Comment: I will reword the question. For now,

Inheritance is right soln here. Basically what I am asking is: B has a pure virtual function. Its derived classes N, and M are supposed to override it (cannot leave it pure virtual in derived ones, as M and N are used for making objects.). I have an implementation of function for M, but not for N. 

How to override in N?

Comment: Are you sure inheritance and not composition is the solution to your problem? What is the actual problem you're trying to solve? There *may* be a better solution.

Comment: @Mayank Can my answer solve your question? Thanks.

Comment: We're telling you that inheritance is *NOT* the right solution here. If `B` has a virtual method, that means that every derived class implements that method. If `N` does not implement that method, then `N` MUST NOT inherit from `B`, because `N` is not a `B`.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a `dynamic_cast` from `M::Foo` to see if the `Bar()` method is available.

I've added a `Bar_able` interface which can be used to tag a derived `M` class as having a `Bar` method.  The dynamic cast could be made directly against `M*` itself, if this is a one-off situation.

I have to caution that this does not appear to be a good design to me.  As a coworker of mine likes to say, "Inheritance is the root class of all evil."

```
#include <iostream>

namespace {

struct Bar_able {
    virtual void Bar() = 0;
protected:
    virtual ~Bar_able() = default;
};

struct B {
    void Foo();
protected:
    virtual ~B() = default;
};

struct M : B, Bar_able {
    void Bar() override;
};

struct N : B {
};

} // anon

int main() {
    M m;
    N n;
    m.Foo();
    n.Foo();
}

// - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - -

void B::Foo() {
    if (auto bar{ dynamic_cast<Bar_able*>(this) }) bar->Bar();
}

void M::Bar() {
    std::cout << "M::Bar has been called\n";
}
```

Comment: Thanks. Is there a simple way if I do not have to use bar_able interface, and derive M using it.

bar() is a function I want M to have, and to be called from B::Foo(). I do not want to have a separate interface for a single one off function.

Comment: @MayankDhiman • `if (auto m{ dynamic_cast<M*>(this) }) m->Bar();`

Comment: That helped! but, I am in a circular dependency problem now. Class M is importing header for the base class. To use this instrument, I have to import header for class M in base class. Which will cause a circular dependency. Not a good design. But, what should be the way to tackle it for now?

Comment: @Mayank • Do you see how my code avoided the circular dependency problem?

Comment: Is there any way to avoid it without using the Bar_able interface? I am sorry, C++ is a new stuff for me, so just trying to learn. Please bare with me. 

In my case, M, N, and B are in separate files, and if I try this, I have to import M in B's file, and B is already there in M's file. Which causes a circular dependency. I don't want to have a separate interface, and let B be derived from it as well for a single function. Is there any workaround, sounds like a simple problem but, not able to find the answer yet. Plmk, if any part of this problem is not understood.

Comment: @Mayank • The `Bar_able` interface is to make it easier to check if the `Bar` method is available.  It does not need to be used, but then you need to check (`dynamic_cast`) for each class by name in the `B::Foo` implementation.  If your code has a circular dependency problem, it is orthogonal to this problem.  Notice that my code has no circular dependency (and even if I remove `Bar_able`, it still will not have a circular dependency).

Comment: Got it. But in your case the func is is there in public. Is there any way if I want to use that function in protected mode. 

I tried doing it. But it couldn’t access it when it was protected

Comment: @Mayank • That is what `friend` is for.

Answer (score 1):

Is the code below something that meets what you are thinking? The code allows only instantiation on M and N but not B.

The code contains uses for both local stack and dynamic allocation. I added dynamic allocation in order to make sure there was no memory leak by testing. I was using MSVC in VS2022.

```
#include <iostream>

class B {
public:
    virtual ~B() {}
    void do_something() { DoSomething(); }
protected:
    B() {}
private:
    virtual void DoSomething() { std::cout << "Doing in B.\n"; }
};

class M : public B {
private:
    virtual void DoSomething() { std::cout << "Doing in M.\n"; }
};

class N : public B {
};

int main()
{
    std::cout << "Use for local embedded.\n";
    M m;
    N n;
    m.do_something();
    n.do_something();
    std::cout << "Use for dynamic allocation.\n";
    B* b1 = new M;
    B* b2 = new N;
    b1->do_something();
    b2->do_something();
    delete b2;
    delete b1;
    return 0;
}
```

The output is:

```
Use for local embedded.
Doing in M.
Doing in B.
Use for dynamical allocation.
Doing in M.
Doing in B.
```